# How can i get refresh token from xero custom connetion

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory, xero-api, linked-service

How can i get refresh token from xero custom connetion, when i work with previous account i could get this refresh token. but now it it now provided.now when i use this https://identity.xero.com/connect/token  result is only {
"access_token": "########################################################################",
"expires_in": 1800,
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "app.connections marketplace.billing"
}.
refresh token is not included in result

in here "https://devblog.xero.com/introducing-custom-connections-72c32297382" he mention about "Goodbye refresh tokens". is it means cant we get this refresh token now????

currently i worked on poc, here we used Azure Datafactory, and need to create xero linked service in oauth2.0. but in there refresh token is required

can we get refresh token from xero custom connection(free trail(developer purpose)) oauth2.0

Answer (score 0):

Custom connections do not use refresh tokens, you just request a new access token.

Most connectors eg Azure Datafactory are built for the standard codeflow web applications and so we would suggest that you stop using the custom connection and create a web app instead.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/overview/

Comment: I used free account, also i created web app, its also not provide this refresh token.               i created a account previously(15/03/2023) and then that was work fine(That provide refresh token), that is a problem

Comment: @chamithrasintha please can you raise a case with Xero Support by emailing api@xero.com so we can look into your  specific web app. Please can you include the app's name and client id in the email body